# How to have Gradle plugin set dependencies to the plugin jar?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm creating a JDiff plugin. Since it's essentially a Javadoc task, I'm following https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:classpath:

```
dependencies {
  jDiffDoclet files('${PLUGIN_JAR_PATH}')
}
```

But I'd like the plugin to do this work on behalf of the user.

So far, the plugin's `apply` method has:

```
project.configurations {
  jDiffDoclet
}

final xmlNewerTask = getJDiffTask(project).doFirst {
  options.with {
      docletpath = project.configurations.jDiffDoclet.files.asType(List)
      doclet = 'jdiff.JDiff'
  }
}
```

Somehow, the plugin needs to reference its own jar. Alternatively, in the end, all that's really needed is to be able to set `docletpath` but that still requires referencing the plugin's own jar.

Comment: In your plugin `apply()` method couldnt you do `project.getConfigurations.create()` and `configuration.getDependencies.add` ?

Comment: What is it precisely that gets passed into `add`? How does it refer to its own jar file?

Comment: @RaGe, I've added more info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin is added to a project correctly and it resolves correctly, you can get a path to its jar location in gradle cache using:

```
project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.find{it.name == 'foo-plugin-name-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' }
```

Comment: The plugin would have to know the name of the jar, including its version. Is there a way to that information through `DefaultPluginManager`?

Comment: Oh, OTOH, rather than testing for an exact match on the `name`, it could just test for `startsWith` (although that may get too many hits).

Comment: I thought this was inside your own plugin, so you should know the name? You can get around version by using `contains` instead of exact match maybe.

Comment: well.. hopefully your user isn't adding mutiple versions of the same plugin to their buildscript classpath :) ref:many hits

Comment: I was more concerned about name clashes. I'll dig around a bit more to see if the info (including version) can be found through `DefaultPluginManager`. If I don't find it, I'll resort to inexact matches as you've suggested. Thanks.

Comment: You should use the full plugin name except the version in the startswith, so it only matches your plugin. If you're still worried, you could use findAll and throw a warning on multiple matches